Define a generic C# function that returns the same collection type as its parameter
Assuming I want to write a .NET extension .NullIfEmpty() that should apply to any type that implements IReadOnlyCollection<T>.
I can do this by writing
public static IReadOnlyCollection<E> NullIfEmpty<E>(this IReadOnlyCollection<E> c)
  => c.Count == 0 ? null : c;

But this discards the type of the collection which is very counterproductive.
To return the type of the parameter the generic type must be the type of the collection. But now I cannot restrict this type to implement IReadOnlyCollection<>
(and there is no non-generic interface to get only the count - another sad story).
public static C NullIfEmpty<C>(this C c) where C : IReadOnlyCollection<> // error!
  => c.Count == 0 ? null : c;

So, I need another generic parameter for the element type.
But when I write
public static C NullIfEmpty<C, E>(this C collection) where C : IReadOnlyCollection<E>
  => c.Count == 0 ? null : c;

the type inference fails to match e.g. List<string>.
Obviously it cannot infer two type parameters from a single argument.
How to write such a function? Is it just impossible?
The context is .NET Framework 4.8.1, i.e. C# 7.3.

@RyanWilson, generic type parameters are always resolved at compile time. The compiler ensures type safety. Otherwise you would have a dynamic language which is not type-safe.

The OP means that the static return type will not be List<E>.

Yes, this is the runtime type, but the static type is still IReadOnlyCollection<T>. He wants concrete collection type as generic type, so that is the exact same type is returned at compile time (not at runtime). So, the static typeof(C) should be e.g. List<T>.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks for the info but I don't even see how that is useful in any way.

Agree. Btw.: same error with C# 13.

IReadOnlyCollection<T> is defined to be covariant over the generic parameter T since it is read only. So you don't really need to know the precise item type, you can constrain it to simply IReadOnlyCollection<object> and it should be fine for Framework 4.8.
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<T>
public interface IReadOnlyCollection<out T> : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<out T>

public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static TCollection NullIfEmpty<TCollection>(this TCollection collection)
        where TCollection : IReadOnlyCollection<object>
      => collection.Count == 0 ? default : collection;
}

You may also use the non-generic ICollection type as well, though it is more permissive than what you're asking for. But it is one of the original .net types and it's defined as a collection with a known count of items. This is implemented by all types that implement the generic version ICollection<T> so you get this for free for your use cases.

Covariance does not work in general since it does not cover structs because of the required boxing operations.
E.g. it does not work for a set of Guid.

I don't think you'll be able to infer both type arguments like that, no.
If you only ever need this for collections of reference types, and if you were you could use covariance:
public static C NullIfEmpty<C>(this C collection) where C : class, IReadOnlyList<object>
    => collection.Count() == 0 ? null : collection;

That won't work for List<int> etc of course. You could write an extension method for the non-generic IEnumerable, but that would require actually starting to enumerate:
public static C NullIfEmpty<C>(this C collection) where C : class, IEnumerable
{
    var iterator = collection.GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        return iterator.MoveNext() ? collection : null;
    }
    finally
    {
        (iterator as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }
}

As noted by Olivier in the comments, we can use the non-generic ICollection as well, which avoids iterating due to it having a Count property - and almost all collections implement ICollection:
public static C NullIfEmpty<C>(this C collection) where C : class, ICollection
    => collection.Count == 0 ? null : collection;

Or if you don't mind it not being an extension method, and you don't mind being explicit about the element type, but want to infer the collection type, this works:
public static class Collections<E>
{
    public static C NullIfEmpty<C>(C collection) where C : class, IReadOnlyList<E>
        => collection.Count() == 0 ? null : collection;
}
...
List<int> a = new();
List<int> b = Collections<int>.NullIfEmpty(a);


where C : class, System.Collections.ICollection actually works. I don't see a good reason why the collection should be restricted to be readonly. NullIfEmpty is known to not alter the collection. And even e.g. ImmutableHashSet<T> implements ICollection.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes: Good point, I'll add that as another option.
